# recyclerview get jerk while I am clicking check box

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with checkbox list items. Now I scroll to end of recyclerview and click ckeckbox. When I click checkbox recyclerview get jerk and list moved to little top to the list.

Here I post my Adapter code for your review.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mChkEquipments.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.txt_equiment_number.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.divider.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(position==0){
            holder.txt_equiment_number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.text_hookEqmnt.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getInspectionName());
            holder.divider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txt_equiment_number.setText(mEquipmentNumber);
        }else{
            holder.text_hookEqmnt.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getInspectionName());
        }
        holder.text_hookEqmnt.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getInspectionName());
        holder.txt_equiment_number.setText(mEquipmentNumber);
        holder.mChkEquipments.setChecked(mArrayList.get(position).getInspectionStatus());
        if(mArrayList.get(position).getInspectionStatus()){
            holder.mChkEquipments.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.route_check);
        }else{
            holder.mChkEquipments.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.route_close);
        }

        holder.mChkEquipments.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                /*holder.mChkEquipments.setChecked(isChecked);
                mArrayList.get(position).setInspectionStatus(isChecked);
                updateStatus(mArrayList.get(position).getId(),isChecked);
                if(isChecked){
                    holder.mChkEquipments.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.route_check);
                }else{
                    holder.mChkEquipments.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.route_close);
                }*/
            }
        });

        if (position % 2 != 0) {
            holder.mVIew.setBackgroundResource(R.color.list_alternative_bg);
        } else {
            holder.mVIew.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        }
    }
```

And also I tried with OnClickListener too. But Same problem I am facing.

```
holder.mChkEquipments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final boolean isChecked = holder.mChkEquipments.isChecked();
                holder.mChkEquipments.setChecked(isChecked);
                mArrayList.get(position).setInspectionStatus(isChecked);
                updateStatus(mArrayList.get(position).getId(),isChecked);
                if(isChecked){
                    holder.mChkEquipments.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.route_check);
                }else{
                    holder.mChkEquipments.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.route_close);
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: May I know what is the reason for down vote??

Comment: take a look at google io 2017 ui performance session to learn how to "de-janking" your app ... i bet on `updateStatus`

Comment: Sure. I will check.

Comment: @Selvin.. I post the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is changing the image while clicking the check box.

The problem happening here.

```
if(isChecked){
    holder.mChkEquipments.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.route_check);
   }else{
        holder.mChkEquipments.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.route_close);
   }
```

To avoid this problem I changed the image in xml instead from java class.

I created the xml in drawable folder and using following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/route_close" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/route_check" />
</selector>
```

and set this in checkbox background. Then issue is fixed. This may be helpful to others.